# How to extract Cookie Data in JMeter

Tags: cookies, jmeter

I am new to JMeter and creating JMeter scripts on .Net Framework version 4.5.

I am facing a challenge or issue that how to extract/capture values like .ASPXAuth, AuthToken, Sesson ID generating on login into web application as Cookie Data but unable to use the same in the subsequent requests as there is no parameter available in Requests.

Actually, I need to extract the cookie data value from response header and to use it further in the subsequent requests. Please share the steps to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add cookies support to your JMeter script just add a [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your test plan.

The HTTP Cookie Manager automatically extracts the cookies from the [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) response header, checks their validity and adds them to the next request if domain and path of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers match the Cookie's domain and path.

So in the majority of cases it's sufficient to just add the HTTP Cookie Manager in order to get browser-like behaviour when it comes to cookies handling.

If you need to use the values of the cookies somewhere else, i.e. in a request parameter you can add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
CookieManager.save.cookies=true
```

upon JMeter restart the incoming cookies values will be stored as [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) so you will be able to access the value of  `.ASPXAuth` cookie as `${COOKIE_.ASPXAuth}`, the value of `AuthToken` cookie as `${COOKIE_AuthToken}`, etc.

More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)

Comment: Thanks for the response. If possible please share the steps/screenshots that how to extract Cookie Value and add them to the next request in JMeter.

Comment: Actually my main concern is that how will we handle it for multiple login or user credentials. when I am trying to do it for multiple users passing through CSV and at that time no AuthToken and .ASPXAuth parameter values are getting generated or displayed in Response Headers under View Result Tree in JMeter. Please respond soon.

Comment: Double check the response data, variables from CSV and the credentials you're sending using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script), if you don't see the cookies most probably your login fails somewhere somehow

Comment: Thanks. It's working now.